# EntityFramework 6.1.3 enable-migrations "The domain manager specified by the host could not be instantiated"

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, azure

I've got a brand new application hosted on Azure using a SQL database hosted in azure.  I've got the authentication (using ASP.NET Identity) working as well as my first table with some data (that I designed database-first).  I used EF's generate Context from database-first, which created my model class and my Context.  Now I'm ready to add a second table, but I figured I'd try doing it code-first this time.

I went to the Package Manager Console and typed `Enable-Migrations`.

I get this error:

```
Exception calling "CreateDomain" with "3" argument(s): "The domain manager specified by the host could not be instantiated."
At C:\Users\Alex\projects\SpellbookAPI\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:717 char:5
+     $domain = [AppDomain]::CreateDomain('Migrations', $null, $info)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeLoadException
```

and a whole bunch of these:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Alex\projects\SpellbookAPI\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:718 char:5
+     $domain.SetData('project', $project)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Any idea what's causing these/how to fix it?

EDIT:  I don't know if it's important to mention, the application is a .NET 4.6.1 Web API with Authentication

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being an issue with Visual Studio 15 Preview.  Once I tried to enable migrations using VS2015, it worked just fine.